# React Native - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-reanimated:generateJsonModelDebug'

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I am facing this issue. Can anyone help me out? 
while running react native application. I am getting this error. I installed all the dependencies and software that were required even though I was getting this

```
> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Native libs debug enabled: false
Android gradle plugin: 4.1.1
Gradle: 6.7.1
building Reanimated2

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-reanimated:generateJsonModelDebug'.
> CMake '3.18.1' was not found in PATH or by cmake.dir property.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with
 --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! offket@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new version of `react-native-reanimated` (v2.10.0) has this issue as discussed [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3513) and [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3516). A [PR](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/3521) has been created to fix this issue. So till a new version is released, you can try these workarounds -

Install CMake 3.18.1 using CLI or Android Studio.

CLI

```
$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager "cmake;3.18.1"
```

Android Studio

Go to `Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Show Package Details` and select CMake version 3.18.1 and Apply.

Rebuild the app. If it's still failing then downgrade the package to previous version and rebuild.

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated@2.9.1
OR
npm install react-native-reanimated@2.9.1
```