# Unable To Run Android React-Native App Due to CMake Path Versions

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, cmake

I am trying to run my react-native application but whenver i do it crashes and gives me this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-reanimated:generateJsonModelDebug'.
> CMake '3.18.1' was not found in PATH or by cmake.dir property. 
CMake '3.22.4' found in PATH did not match requested version '3.18.1'.
```

I don't understand what this means, i believe it has something to do with the react-native-reanimated package. this package has many issues and i do not know how to resolve them.

Any help?

Comment: I have answered it here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73511473/1427309

Answer (score 3):

It means you have to update the cmake version and export to your path directory.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Access SDK MANAGER
3. Access tools and found CMake
4. Click Show Package details
5. Then install the version 3.18.1